# My hibernate application shows message in console and shows session closed error on browser

Tags: hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping

Ive downloaded this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse/) and could successfully run it on my computer.

Once I removed the contact class and added my class which is called developer, it shows the following error.

**Error**

```
    type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1243: Filter execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/viralpatel/contact/model/Contact;

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.viralpatel.contact.model.Contact

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

                <mapping class="net.viralpatel.contact.model.Developer" />


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**ContactManager**

```
 package net.viralpatel.contact.controller;


import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import net.viralpatel.contact.model.Developer;
import net.viralpatel.contact.util.HibernateUtil;

public class ContactManager extends HibernateUtil {

    public void add(Developer developer) {
                System.err.println("Here is add");
        //Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();
        session1.save(developer);
        session1.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**Developer**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package net.viralpatel.contact.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Jack Ramzi
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="developer")
public class Developer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8767337896773261247L;

    private int id;
    private String contact;
    private int phone_1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.id = ID;
    }

    @Column(name="contact")
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String Contact) {
        this.contact = Contact;
    }

    @Column(name="phone_1")
    public int getPhone_1() {
        return phone_1;
    }

    public void setPhone_1(int Phone_1) {
        this.phone_1 = Phone_1;
    }


  }
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
                    System.out.println("********************************in session");
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    System.out.println("this exception");
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**ContactAction**

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.view;

import net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactManager;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import net.viralpatel.contact.model.Developer;

public class ContactAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149826260758390091L;
    private Developer developer;
    private ContactManager linkController;

    public ContactAction() {
        linkController = new ContactManager();
    }

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String add() {
        try{
            System.out.println("in add of contactAction");
        developer = new Developer();
        developer.setID(1);
        developer.setContact("jack");
        developer.setPhone_1(123344);
        linkController.add(developer);}
        catch(Exception e){
                                System.out.println("this exception 2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Developer getDeveloper() {
        return developer;
    }

    public void setDeveloper(Developer developer) {
        this.developer = developer;
    }

    public ContactManager getLinkController() {
        return linkController;
    }

    public void setLinkController(ContactManager linkController) {
        this.linkController = linkController;
    }
}
```

**Developer Table**

```
 id int(11)
 contact varchar(15)
 phone_1 int(15)
```

Comment: I would have already, if the hbm file was also there. Without that its a incomplete question (not worthy of downvote I am sure).

Answer (score 1):

At first look it seems like a possibility of 2 issues

1. ContactManager object which you are trying to save is null
2. Your variable name 'Contact' is incorrect, it should be 'contact' (some hibernate thingy)
3. Where is your hbm.xml file ? There may be a reference of 'Contact' the class in that file still around somewhere

Edit

**Solutions**

1. Put a `if (developer != null)` before your 'save(developer)'
2. Rename `Contact` to `contact`
3. Put the hbm file contents on the question, without that cant review the mapping

Hope it clear now.

Edit 2 :

Do a clean build. Its possible your build is not updated.

Comment: thank I have noticed these problems from the stacktrace but do not know, how to solve them

Comment: I have posted the hbm.xml  there is no trace of contact in it.

Comment: I am using the annotations for mappings  not the xml file.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry did not notice that.

Comment: I cleaned the projct and found out there is a contact.class in WEB-INF even after deleting that it is still looking for contact class, question is updated.

Comment: Good to know that my advice helped.